# The height of textview with attributed text is wrong sometimes in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm forcing the height constraint of my textview with the following code

```
func setHeightConstraint(textView: UITextView) {
    textView.sizeToFit()
    textView.layoutIfNeeded()

    var newFrame:CGRect=textView.frame
    newFrame.size.height=textView.contentSize.height
    textView.frame=newFrame
    println(textView.contentSize.height)
    textViewHeightConstraints.constant=textView.contentSize.height
}
```

My text view contains attributedText with links, bold, italic and so on..

It works well sometimes, but does not on other times.

I figured by printing textView.contentSize.height, that textView.contentSize.height is  sometimes much smaller than it should be.

I used that code snippet with normal text with no issue, so I guess it is a problem about attributedText.

I tried googling and tried this and that code with no luck.

How should I measure the correct height of the textView when it contains attributedText??

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

(I can read Object-C code also though I prefer swift, so Object-C answer is  appreciated as well!!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to make a text view whose height can be adjusted to fit its contents. This is how I do it:

```
func adjustHeight() {
    let sz = self.tv.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.tv.bounds.width, 10000))
    self.heightConstraint.constant = ceil(sz.height)
}
```

In that code, `self.tv` is the text view and `self.heightConstraint` is the internal constraint that sets its height.

There are major problems with your code, by the way. In particular: If you are using constraints you must not use `frame`! The constraints position and size the object; that is what they are for.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to use frame, not constraints.
And your height measuring code works like charm!!